# Rails 5 Polymorphic association with enum is throwing `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Log` model, which belongs to many models through polymorphic association. For the type column, it is using `enum`, which was working fine with Rails 4.2, but after upgrading to Rails 5, it is throwing `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer`

```
class Log
  enum loggable_type: %i[a b c d]
  # ...
end
```

```
class A
  has_many :logs, as: :loggable, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end
```

When fetching logs:

```
a = A.find id
a.logs
```

It throws the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "A")
: SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."loggable_id" = $1 AND "logs"."loggable_type" = $2
```

With Rails 4.2, the same code was working fine. Here's the same query:

```
> a.logs
  Log Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."loggable_id" = $1 AND "logs"."loggable_type" = $2  [["loggable_id", 1111111], ["loggable_type", 0]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

What do I need to do to make it work for Rails 5?

Comment: You can maybe try to explicitly define the enum, `enum loggable_type: {a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C'}`, because right now if you do Logs.loggable_types you get `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}`

Comment: migrate `loggable_type` column type to string

Comment: Thanks, guys for trying to help. I've found a solution and posted the same.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery let me try your solution and see if it works, but I've already fixed the problem using polymorphic_integer_type gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Rails docs and the issue raised [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27149), a polymorphic type column is supposed to be a string, not an integer. With this approach, I had to migrate the old data.

Fortunately, there's a gem [polymorphic_integer_type](https://github.com/clio/polymorphic_integer_type) which exists to solve the exact same problem.

After including the gem in Gemfile and running bundle, all I had to do was this:

```
class Log
  include PolymorphicIntegerType::Extensions
  belongs_to :loggable, polymorphic: { 1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D' }
end
```

And it worked like a charm.